# Sending request reponse message on Artemis using C#

Tags: c#, activemq-artemis, request-response

I am trying to implement a request response pattern in C# with the ArtemisNetClient, but having a bit of trouble finding out how to do so in a more generic way in a real solution.

I was able to do something like this in two console applications based on some Java examples:

**Sender**

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    var endpoint = Endpoint.Create("localhost", 5672, "guest", "guest");
    var connection = await connectionFactory.CreateAsync(endpoint);

    string guid = new Guid().ToString();

    var requestAddress = "TRADE REQ1";
    var responseAddress = "TRADE RESP";

    Message message = new Message("BUY AMD 1000 SHARES");
    message.SetCorrelationId(guid);
    message.ReplyTo = responseAddress;

    var producer = await connection.CreateProducerAsync(requestAddress, RoutingType.Anycast);
    await producer.SendAsync(message);

    var consumer = await connection.CreateConsumerAsync(responseAddress, RoutingType.Anycast);
    var responseMessage = await consumer.ReceiveAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(responseMessage.GetBody<string>());
    
}
```

**Receiver**

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create connection
    var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    var endpoint = Endpoint.Create("localhost", 5672, "guest", "guest");
    var connection = await connectionFactory.CreateAsync(endpoint);

    var requestAddress = "TRADE REQ1";

    // Create consumer to receive trade request messages
    var consumer = await connection.CreateConsumerAsync(requestAddress, RoutingType.Anycast);
    var message = await consumer.ReceiveAsync();

    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {message.GetBody<string>()}");

    // Confirm trade request and ssend response message
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.ReplyTo))
    {
        Message responseMessage = new Message("Confirmed trade request");
        responseMessage.SetCorrelationId(message.CorrelationId);
        var producer = await connection.CreateProducerAsync(message.ReplyTo);
        await producer.SendAsync(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

This worked as expected, but I'd like to have something more down the line of what is described in [this article](https://havret.io/activemq-artemis-net-core), except it doesn't have any examples of a request response pattern.

To elaborate, I currently have two services that I want to communicate across.

In **service 1** I want to create and publish a message and then wait for a response to enrich the instance object and save it to a database. I currently have this, but it lacks the await response message.

```
public async Task<Instance> CreateInstance(Instance instance)
{
    await _instanceCollection.InsertOneAsync(instance);

    var @event = new InstanceCreated
    {
        Id = instance.Id,
        SiteUrl = instance.SiteUrl
    };

    await _messageProducer.PublishAsync(@event);

    return instance;
}
```

I figured I might need to setup a temporary queue/connection or something in the `PublishAsync()` and change it to e.g. `Task<Message>` to support returning a response message. But how would I go about doing that? Would I have to do a new connectionfactory + `CreateConsumerAsync` etc. like in the console app example?

```
public class MessageProducer
{
    private readonly IAnonymousProducer _producer;

    public MessageProducer(IAnonymousProducer producer)
    {
        _producer = producer;
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync<T>(T message, string replyTo = null, string correlationId = null)
    {
        var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
        var address = typeof(T).Name;
        var msg = new Message(serialized);
        if (replyTo != null && correlationId != null)
        {
            msg.CorrelationId = correlationId;
            msg.ReplyTo = replyTo;
        }
        await _producer.SendAsync(address, msg);
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync<T>(T message, string routeName, string replyTo = null, string correlationId = null)
    {
        var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
        var address = routeName;
        var msg = new Message(serialized);
        if(replyTo != null && correlationId != null)
        {
            msg.CorrelationId = correlationId;
            msg.ReplyTo = replyTo;
        }
        await _producer.SendAsync(address, msg);
    }
}
```

In **Service 2** I have a `InstanceCreatedConsumer` which receives messages, but again it lacks a way to return response messages.

```
public class InstanceCreatedConsumer : ITypedConsumer<InstanceCreated>
{
    private readonly MessageProducer _messageProducer;
    public InstanceCreatedConsumer(MessageProducer messageProducer)
    {
        _messageProducer = messageProducer;
    }
    public async Task ConsumeAsync(InstanceCreated message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // consume message and return response
    }
}
```

I figured I might be able to extend the `ActiveMqExtensions` class with a `ConsumeAsync` and `HandleMessage` that handles the response message with a return value, but I haven't gotten as far yet.

```
public static IActiveMqBuilder AddTypedConsumer<TMessage, TConsumer>(this IActiveMqBuilder builder,
    RoutingType routingType)
    where TConsumer : class, ITypedConsumer<TMessage>
{
    builder.Services.TryAddScoped<TConsumer>();
    builder.AddConsumer(typeof(TMessage).Name, routingType, HandleMessage<TMessage, TConsumer>);
    return builder;
}

private static async Task HandleMessage<TMessage, TConsumer>(Message message, IConsumer consumer, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken token)
    where TConsumer : class, ITypedConsumer<TMessage>
{
    try
    {
        var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TMessage>(message.GetBody<string>());
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var typedConsumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TConsumer>();
        await typedConsumer.ConsumeAsync(msg, token);
        await consumer.AcceptAsync(message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // todo
    }
}
```

Am I totally wrong in what I am trying to achieve here, or is it just not possible with the ArtemisNetClient?

Maybe someone has an example or can confirm whether I am down the right path, or maybe I should be using a different framework.

I am new to this kind of communication through messages like ActiveMQ Artemis, so any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 2.7.0 ArtemisNetClient introduces `IRequestReplyClient` interface that can be used to implement a request-response messaging pattern. With `ArtemisNetClient.Extensions.DependencyInjection` this may look as follows:

**Client Side:**

First you need to register your typed request-reply client in DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /*...*/ 
    var endpoints = new[] { Endpoint.Create(host: "localhost", port: 5672, "guest", "guest") };
    services.AddActiveMq("bookstore-cluster", endpoints)
            .AddRequestReplyClient<MyRequestReplyClient>();
    /*...*/
}
```

`MyRequestReplyClient` is your custom class that expects the `IRequestReplyClient` to be injected via the constructor. Once you have your custom class, you can either expose the `IRequestReplyClient` directly or encapsulate sending logic inside of it:

```
public class MyRequestReplyClient
{
    private readonly IRequestReplyClient _requestReplyClient;
    public MyRequestReplyClient(IRequestReplyClient requestReplyClient)
    {
        _requestReplyClient = requestReplyClient;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
        var address = typeof(TRequest).Name;
        var msg = new Message(serialized);
        var response = await _requestReplyClient.SendAsync(address, msg, cancellationToken);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResponse>(response.GetBody<string>());
    }
}
```

That's it regarding the client-side.

**Worker side**

To implement the worker side you can (as you suggested), change the `ITypedConsumer` interface to return the message that would be sent back, or you can provide the additional data (`ReplyTo` and `CorrelationId` headers) so you can send the response back as part of your consumer logic. I prefer the latter as it's a more flexible option in my opinion.

Modified `ITypedConsumer` might look like that:

```
public interface ITypedConsumer<in T>
{
    public Task ConsumeAsync(T message, MessageContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Where `MessageContext` is just a simple dto:

```
public class MessageContext
{
    public string ReplyTo { get; init; }
    public string CorrelationId { get; init; }
}
```

`HandleMessage` extension method:

```
private static async Task HandleMessage<TMessage, TConsumer>(Message message, IConsumer consumer, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken token)
    where TConsumer : class, ITypedConsumer<TMessage>
{
    var msg = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TMessage>(message.GetBody<string>());
    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var typedConsumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TConsumer>();
    var messageContext = new MessageContext
    {
        ReplyTo = message.ReplyTo,
        CorrelationId = message.CorrelationId
    };
    await typedConsumer.ConsumeAsync(msg, messageContext, token);
    await consumer.AcceptAsync(message);
}
```

`MessageProducer` has to be slightly changed as well, so you can explicitly pass address and `CorrelationId`:

```
public class MessageProducer
{
    private readonly IAnonymousProducer _producer;

    public MessageProducer(IAnonymousProducer producer)
    {
        _producer = producer;
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync<T>(string address, T message, MessageContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
        var msg = new Message(serialized);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.CorrelationId))
        {
            msg.CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId;
        }

        await _producer.SendAsync(address, msg, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And finally, the exemplary consumer could work like that:

```
public class CreateBookConsumer : ITypedConsumer<CreateBook>
{
    private readonly MessageProducer _messageProducer;

    public CreateBookConsumer(MessageProducer messageProducer)
    {
        _messageProducer = messageProducer;
    }

    public async Task ConsumeAsync(CreateBook message, MessageContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var @event = new BookCreated
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = message.Title,
            Author = message.Author,
            Cost = message.Cost,
            InventoryAmount = message.InventoryAmount,
            UserId = message.UserId,
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        await _messageProducer.PublishAsync(context.ReplyTo, @event, new MessageContext
        {
            CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @Hav. I'm no longer on this project, but it was great to use and we already made it work on the previous version. Will let the new team know of your update.

Comment: Sure thing. For future if you have any questions regarding the lib, please ask them also on project's discussions page. I'm answering there right away.  --> https://github.com/Havret/dotnet-activemq-artemis-client/discussions

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in the ArtemisNetClient that would simplify the request/response pattern from your application's point of view. One might expect something akin to JMS' [`QueueRequestor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueRequestor.html), but I don't see anything like that in the code, and I don't see anything like that listed in the documentation.

I recommend you simply do in your application what you did in your example (i.e. manually create the consumer & producer to deal with the responses on each end respectively). The only change I would recommend is to re-use connections so you create as few as possible. A connection pool would be ideal here.

---

For what it's worth, it looks to me like the first [release of ArtemisNetClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArtemisNetClient) was just 3 months ago and [according to GitHub](https://github.com/Havret/dotnet-activemq-artemis-client/graphs/contributors) all but 2 of the commits to the code-base came from one developer. ArtemisNetClient may grow into a very successful C# client implementation, but at this point it seems relatively immature. Even *if* the existing code is high quality if there isn't a solid community around the client then chances are it won't have the support necessary to get timely bug fixes, new features, etc. Only time will tell.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for since I've seen a number of Java examples where they create a temporary session queue, but I was unable to find anything similar in the ArtemisNetClient. Thanks for you're input.